# The following package have unmet dependencies (Debian after testing upgrade)

Tags: debian, downgrade, debian-buster

Debian after upgrade to 10 version ask me to autoremove several packages.
So i said "Yes" and now everything is bad.

Here is what i see when i try to install mysql-server:

```
apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: default-mysql-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is when i try to install default-mysql-server:

```
apt-get install default-mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-mysql-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is when try to install mariadb-server-10.1

```
apt-get install mariadb-server-10.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server-10.1 : Depends: libdbi-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Here is when i try to install libdbi-perl

```
apt-get install libdbi-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdbi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.24.1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And here is when i try to install perlapi-5.24.1

```
apt-get install perlapi-5.24.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package perlapi-5.24.1 is a virtual package provided by:
  perl-base 5.24.1-3+deb9u5 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'perlapi-5.24.1' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Hi! In which way did you *update* Debian? Could you please provide the output of `dpkg --audit`? And which entries are in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: dpkg --audi - nothing

Comment: deb https://deb.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ stable/updates main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb https://apt.patrickwu.space/ stable main

Comment: Do you also have issues with `apt update`? Now that you're on *Debian Buster (testing)*, I don't think that you need the *stable (Stretch)* repositories anymore, so you should remove them from your `sources.list` (or just comment them). You may also want to add `deb security.debian.org/debian-security testing/updates main`. Then you can do these steps: `apt autoclean` then `apt clean`, `apt update` and look what's the output of the last line (be sure to use `apt update` not `apt-get`). Use `apt list --upgradable` to see if there is something to upgrade and finally do `apt upgrade`.

Comment: I had try all this. No changes.

Comment: Sorry. Well, probably you should consider taking a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499361/291387) on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and try downgrading back to stable and retry the upgrade to buster again. Or you post your question there or on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). You should know, stackoverflow actually is about programming.

Comment: Already had try this - does not help.

Comment: I also broke my Debian once (because of something else). At that time I created a bootstick and reinstalled Debian while preserving data and so only the root partition was renewed. Of course, I made a backup of my home directory before and just moved it back after reinstalling. Worked great. In any case: good luck ;-)